# Twig safe html does not work inside macro

Tags: symfony, twig

Using a twig macro on safe content seems to remove the safe flags

```
{% macro identity(value) %}
     {{ value }}
{% endmacro %}
{{  "<br>"| raw }}
{{ _self.identity(  "<br>"| raw) }}
{% autoescape false %}
    {{ _self.identity(  "<br>"| raw) }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

The code above show only 2 `<br>`. Is there a way to disable escaping, or marking my content as safe without editing my twig macro ?

Comment: Maybe you wanted to write `_self.identity( "<br>" ) | raw` if you want the raw result from the function.

Comment: It does not work. I guess this is because in the filter I have `{{ }}` which is equivalent of calling the escaping filter `<br> | e`. My only workaround is to put a raw filter in all my macro and  escaping manually when I need it. 
```{% macro identity(value) %}
     {{ value | raw }}
{% endmacro %}
{{ _self.identity(  no_safe_content ) | e  }}```

Comment: Yes it works only with `{{ value|raw }}`. It looks like that `{{ value }}` escape the HTML tags, calling `{% autoescape false %}` does not change the result since the HTML tags are already transformed to HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed correct that you must put the raw filter in the macro in order to keep whatever tags inside the macro from escaping their input and this would, at least in my opinion, be the expected behavior.

In Twig, macros are not function or filters, they are simply shortcuts that keep you from repeating boilerplate tags and code. It helps, when you create and use a macro, to think of writing the whole code each time you will use it i.e.

Instead of thinking of your macro as a call `{{ _self.identity( "<br>"| raw ) }}` actually think that what you are writing is `{{ {{ "<br>"| raw }} }}` because you are passing the output of the macro's input as a literal, not the expression you have written.

If you would like your macros to operate using the provided input as a template, rather than, as designed, operating on the output of whatever you pass in, you may look at enabling the [`template_from_string`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html) function.